# How do Measure weapons work?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I have made Balthier a Machinist and White Mage, so he has access to Measures.

These seem to be very low fixed damage weapons, which apply buffs on hit. I have tried using one and manually having him attack my other party members to apply Protect.

However in the wider context of the game, they seemed entirely pointless, until I found one which applies Bravery on hit, which is a nice buff I don't currently have access to.

The only premise I can think of is swapping to this weapon, manually applying the buff and then changing weapons again. I don't know how you'd Gambit for them either. If you set an 'Ally: Any => Attack' you could apply Bravery, but the character would not deal any damage to enemies, because you wouldn't have 'Enemy: Nearest => Attack' due to applying Bravery to enemies.

It swapping weapons just to buff the only viable use for Measures, or am I missing some mechanic in their use?

I am playing the Steam release of FF12 Zodiac Age (2018)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premise on [Measures](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XII_weapons#Measures) is correct. These weapons essentially allow for bestowing buffs onto your allies without the use of MP or Items, but it is recommended to switch to a more effective weapon when you are finished.

> Measures have low attack ratings, but ignore defense when used, damage being calculated solely on the weapon's attack. Measures also cause beneficial status effects on hit, so they are to be used to strengthen the party without using MP and should generally be switched out for more conventional weapons after being used

The damage calculated from Measures is low because ignores any stats and solely relies on the Attack Power of the weapon.

> DMG = [Attack Power * Random(1 ~ 1.125)]^2

As far as Gambits, there are some guides, like [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps2/459841-final-fantasy-xii/answers/178695-what-is-a-good-gambit-set-up-for-measures) one, that recommend not setting gambits for Measures and manually triggering the attack on your ally. You will spend more time configuring your gambits back and forth for your different jobs. Since Balthier being your White Mage, you definitely want to use your Gambits for healing and reviving.

There are some Gambits though that could be used remove debuffs rather than apply buffs. One example would be

> Ally: status = Slow

Applying Haste to a Slowed ally with the [Caplier](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Caliper) Measure will counteract the effects and will remove Slow without having to exhaust your White Mage's MP.

Comment: If you are feeling lazy and want to make use of measures anyway - use this answers suggestion of Caliper to fix slow - and use attacking spells for damage - teach your machinist Famfrit to access Graviga (if other job has no attacking spells by default). They are not much use for a one size fits all set up otherwise